# Evaluate a simple tensorflow layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a simple tensorflow model that I want to push a tensor through, but despite my efforts to define an initializer the model claims it's not initialized.  What do I need to do to the model to put it into a state where I can evaluate it (ie run the math)?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def tfDenseTest(dim1,dim2):
    vecs_input = Input(shape=(dim1,dim2),dtype='float32')
    user_att = Dense(100,activation='tanh', kernel_initializer= 'random_uniform', bias_initializer= 'random_uniform')(vecs_input)
    model = Model(vecs_input,user_att)
    return model

dim1 = 5
dim2 = 10
dense = tfDenseTest(dim1, dim2)

for layer in dense.layers:
    print(layer.name, layer.output_shape, [w.shape for w in layer.get_weights()]) 

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((2,dim1,dim2)).astype('float32'))

dense(x).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

Result:

```
input_4 (None, 5, 10) []
dense_4 (None, 5, 100) [(10, 100), (100,)]  <-- dense layer has weights


FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_4/bias
     [[{{node dense_4/bias/read}}]]
     [[{{node model_4/dense_4/Tanh}}]]
```

Comment: I'm running tf 2.9 and without the `.eval(session=...)` this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[.eval()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#eval) is callable only when graph mode is launched in a session. As you are using `TF 2.x` functionalities, you can use .numpy() instead.

Please have a look at this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np

def tfDenseTest(dim1,dim2):
    vecs_input = Input(shape=(dim1,dim2),dtype='float32')
    user_att = Dense(100,activation='tanh', kernel_initializer= 'random_uniform', bias_initializer= 'random_uniform')(vecs_input)
    model = Model(vecs_input,user_att)
    return model

dim1 = 5
dim2 = 10
dense = tfDenseTest(dim1, dim2)

for layer in dense.layers:
    print(layer.name, layer.output_shape, [w.shape for w in layer.get_weights()]) 

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.random((2,dim1,dim2)).astype('float32'))
#dense(x).numpy()
dense(x).numpy().shape

#dense(x).eval(session=tf.compat.v1.Session())
```

Output:

```
input_4 [(None, 5, 10)] []
dense_3 (None, 5, 100) [(10, 100), (100,)]
(2, 5, 100)
```